# Same page shows different content if instead of "localhost" I type the network name in the address bar. How is this possible?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET page that shows different content if instead of "localhost" I type the network name in the address bar.

This appears if I type localhost:
[image]

This appears if I type the network name:
[image]

These are the same pages, if I add a text, the modification appears on both versions.

This happens only on IE, in chrome I always get the same correct page.

How is this possible???

The code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestNoMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="app_Employee.TestNoMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .zzzttt222 {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right:40px;
            border: 1px solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <div class="zzzttt222">element</div>
        <div class="zzzttt222">element</div>
        <div class="zzzttt222">element</div>
        <div class="zzzttt222">element</div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the compatibility view settings in Tools -> Compatibility View settings?  It's possible that either 'localhost' or 'hubpwwks011117' is listed as one of the websites to view in Compatibility View, which would explain the difference when rendered.

Answer (score 0):

As @larsenmc said, probably it's a compatibility view problem. IE likes to put all intranet pages in compatibility view. Maybe IE thinks that one page is intranet and another isn't, creating this difference between both pages.

There is an option in IE to enable or disable compatibility view in intranet pages. Try do uncheck this.